# Inefficient driver.get() performance in Loops with IEDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, iedriverserver

I'm using Selenium IEDriver to execute business operations on site A. When running the code on the server with userX via the command line, I notice that the duration remains stable at around 0.5 seconds throughout the loops. However, when using userY (a Windows agent user, on the same server as userX), the duration increases steadily by 50 milliseconds after each loop, causing our business processes to gradually slow down.

However, this slowdown does not occur if my_url is a login page; it only occurs after I have logged in to site A.

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    start_time = time.time()
    driver.get(my_url)
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = (end_time - start_time) * 1000
    printLogToFile(duration)
```

Please refrain from advising me to use eager or none page load strategies, as in our real-world scenario, we must wait until the page is fully loaded.

OS: Windows Server 2019
IEDriverServer.exe 4.14 64-bit
Browser: Edge (IE Mode: 32-bit)

Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want us to do with this info. If you are running the same code for both tests, it seems like your site has a bug with userY account types.

Comment: Maybe there're some problems with userY's profile which leads to the slow performance.    It's hard to advice with this limited information.

Comment: @YuZhou When I remote desktop to the server using userY and run the code via the command line, the result is the same as when run with userX. The gradual slowdown only occurs when the code is activated by the agent user.

Comment: @JeffC The gradual slowdown only occurs when the code is trigger by the windows agent user, so i dont think has bug with windows userY

Comment: You haven't explained what an "agent user" is. You also never mentioned that you ran the same test from the command line for userX and userY and saw no difference, etc. You need to edit your question and provide more useful information.